# Using react-datepicker with agGrid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, react-datepicker

Im trying to incorporate react-date picker with ag-grid
ag-grid provides documentation on using custom date picker but with using flatpickr
was wondering if anyone has successfully attempted to use react-datepicker with ag-grid and if so, could provide and example?

Ag Grid example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/component-date/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The react-datepicker is a bit more tricky to work with but I have a solution that works:

The `portalId` is key here, it allows us to append the popup to the root which allows the popup to be visible inside the filter menu:

```
<DatePicker
          portalId="root"
          popperClassName="ag-custom-component-popup"
          selected={this.state.date}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
```

Please see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-date-picker?file=index.js)